# Using a JavaFX application as standard program for mp3 files

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a media player using JavaFX right now and I would like to set it as the standard program to open .mp3 files in the future.

I know how to change the standard program. But when the user double clicks a specific file and my program opens up how would I be able to get the path to the file the user clicked on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The path to the file should be passed as a command line argument.

Comment: I assume he means for Windows programming, @James_D. Do you mean that when I double-click on an mp3, which causes my JavaFX program to be called, the file path will be available in the `String args[]` parameter in the `main` method?

Comment: @DavidS Yes, but since this is a JavaFX question you would retrieve the command line arguments by calling `getParameters()` in the `Application` class. And I don't think this is restricted to Windows.

Comment: @James_D how would I pass them to the program though?

Comment: I believe the OS will pass the file name to the program if you open the program by double clicking on a file with which the program is associated. I have no immediate way to test this, though.

Comment: @James_D Yes, that was it. Thanks! Altough I did need to work around a bit, because this only seems to work when the java file is wrapped in a .exe file :D (Using Launch4j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I made it work:

I exported my program from Eclipse. Then I opened an mp3 file using the program but I got an error message saying something like this: "Invalid Win-32 application".
Having used Launch4j before, I tried wrapping my file in an exe file, which made it work perfectly.

I don't know if you are able to set a jar file as a standard program in other OSs, but you can't in Windows, unfortunately. But at least the OS gives you the path to the file the user clicked on!

Thanks again to @James_D !

Comment: I definitely remember associating file types with a jar file, though it was a long time ago. (Java 1.1 on Windows 95, I think, probably around 1997.) No idea if it still works - no windows box available right now to test on.